# Why isn't my media query with a max width of 470px working?

Tags: html, css

If you look at the code, there are two media queries, the one with a max width of 1024 pixels seems to work fine and apply all the styles but the one with a max width of 470 pixels won’t work or apply any of the styles. Why is this happening? Any help appreciated.

https://codepen.io/FreemanW/pen/QWwRBMP?editors=1100

```
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  .banner {
    align-items: flex-end;
  }

  .title-box {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
 ``
```

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your bug. The query is working fine. I'm using chrome version `79.0.3945.117`.

Comment: For example, if the view is 400px then both the css in the `@media (max-width: 1024px)` and the `@media (max-width: 470px)` are true. Both will apply on a small view meaning all css from both @media will apply.

Comment: @bron that's true, but it would work in his case, he is defining the `(max-width: 470px)` after the other style rule, so both would work. Although, as @bron pointed, is better to write: `@media (min-width: 471px) and (max-width: 1024px)` instead of `@media (max-width: 1024px)`

Comment: Ok this is weird, apparently my code is working, but only in codepen? I was originally using atom and opening the index.html in chrome and the 470px media query wasn't working there, but in codepen I guess it is, now im more confused then when I started.

Comment: @FreemanW  if you just open chrome without inspect your browser can't be smaller than 500px but if you open inspect you can resize smaller than this number... I don't know this is in my pc

Comment: @AymanMorsy Yeah im using the inspect thing on chrome, set to responsive it still doesn't work  when I shrink it to the width that should apply the media query

Answer (score 0):

Everything within 470px is also within 1024px, so perhaps there's some sort of conflict going on there.

You could try using `max-width: 470px` and `min-width: 471px`, thus dividing your options into non-overlapping values :)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the media-query with the smaller screen-width is at the end.

That works:

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  h1 {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 470px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>
```

That doesn't works:

```css
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  h1 {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST</h1>
```